# Why does this Python script to replace text in files break the last file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[Source](https://www.litigationsupporttipofthenight.com/single-post/2019/03/31/script-to-find-and-replace-strings-in-multiple-text-files)

```
import os, re

directory = os.listdir('C:/foofolder8')
os.chdir('C:/foofolder8')
for file in directory:
    open_file = open(file,'r')
    read_file = open_file.read()
    regex = re.compile('jersey')
    read_file = regex.sub('york', read_file)
    write_file = open(file, 'w')
    write_file.write(read_file)
```

The script replaces "jersey" in all the files in `C:/foofolder8` with "york". I tried it with three files in the folder and it works. The source notes though that "you may find an error in the last file", which I'm indeed encountering - all text in the last file is simply deleted.

Why does the script break for the last file? The fact that only the last file breaks makes it seem like there's something wrong with the `for` loop, but I don't see what could be wrong. Calling `directory` shows there are three files in the directory as well, which is correct.

Comment: Did you try to close `write_file`? That is, put `write_file.close()` after `write_file.write(read_file)`

Comment: You should also close `open_file` while you're at it. It's best to handle this using a `with` context, like `with open(file, 'r') as open_file:`

Comment: Also, `os.chdir('C:/foofolder8')` is unnecessary and does nothing in the context of your script. For optimal performance, you should compile your regex outside the loop since it doesn't change, and you can reuse the same. Regex compilation is a heavy operation.

Comment: @AbdelhakimAKODADI would suggest writing that as an answer!

Comment: Compiling the same regex again and again inside the loop completely removes any benefits from separately compiling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import os, re
directory = os.listdir('C:/foofolder8')
os.chdir('C:/foofolder8')
for file in directory:
    with open(file,'r') as open_file:
        read_file = open_file.read()
        regex = re.compile('jersey')
        read_file = regex.sub('york', read_file)
    with open (file, 'w') as write_file:
        write_file.write(read_file)
```

Comment: You missed the most important part, which is closing `write_file`

Comment: @AbdelhakimAKODADI : It is good practice to use the `with` keyword when dealing with file objects. The advantage is that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised at some point.

Comment: @AbdelhakimAKODADI source: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: I agree, but that's not my point. Your `with ...` will only close `open_file`. You forgot to close `write_file`

Comment: @AbdelhakimAKODADI : ohh.. modified accordingly